# Проблемы с java.library.path после компиляции в jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, компиляция

Добрый день. Пишу свое десктопное приложение на Java. Работаю в IntelliJ IDEA.
Столкнулся с проблемой после компиляции проекта в jar, пока делал Run с оболочки IntelliJ всё было ОК.
Суть проблемы в кратце такова: в работе программы использую БД FireBird и собственно библиотеку Jaybird-2.2.10

Когда запускаю jar-ник с ярлыка такого вида "java.exe -jar %pathtojarfile%" и вписываю в поле "Рабочая папка", ту где собственно лежит jar файлик, то при попытке сконнектиться с БД получаю такую ошибку [image: Ошибка]

Поискал в интернете что это за "java.library.path", но большинство такие прям специалисты широкого профиля, что даже "не хотят описывать эту элементарщину"(как-то так). Возможно, я просто плохо искал или не понял что от меня требует Java.

Также выложу код, который отвечает за соединение с БД:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FireBirdConnection {

public Connection con = null;
public Statement stmt;
public ResultSet rs;

public FireBirdConnection() {
    String driver = null;
    String url = null;
    String login = null;
    String pass = null;

    Parameters params = null;
    try {
        params = new Parameters();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        url = params.getDataBaseHost();
        login = params.getDataBaseUser();
        pass = params.getDataBasePassword();
        driver = params.getDataBaseDriver();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, pass);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("FireBirdConnection.Cannot find this DB driver classes.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("FireBirdConnection.Cannot connect to this DB.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
 }
```

Параметры подключения хранятся в .properties файле такого вида:

```
DBDRIVER=org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
ADMINPASSWORD=0095
DBUSER=SYSDBA
DBPASS=masterkey
DBHOST=jdbc\:firebirdsql\:local\:D\:\\ExamDB\\EXAM.FDB?encoding\=utf8
```

Если кто талкивался с подобной пролемой, обьясните, пожалуйста в какую сторону мне копать или линканите какую-то адекватную статью по этой теме ориентированную на неопытного специалиста. А я пока пойду читать про обработку исключений чтобы отвлечься немного :) Заранее спасибо.

Comment: простое решение - взять все `.dll` и `.so` файлы из поставки jaybird, положить их в папку `lib` в том же каталоге, где лежит итоговый `jar` и запускать как-то так: `java -Djava.library.path=./lib -jar your_jar.jar`. Потом сделать `.bat` или `.sh` файл с этой командой, и так использовать.

Comment: @zRrr вы правы, всё получилось :) Файлы положил в lib еще с самого начала, но не знал по атрибуты запуска. Спасибо большое :)